# Slope of an equation under cubed root

Tags: calculus

What is the slope of $\sqrt[3]{2x^2+10}$.
I have tried to figure it out, but I am not sure if I am supposed to do the derivative or if it's just m=2

Comment: Is the comma a typo?

Comment: @GabrielH, it might beg cube root of $2x^2 + 10.$

Comment: The slope of that function would depend on where you look ...

Comment: at what point on the graph, is the slope you need.

Comment: @daniel Why do you suspect the slope is 2?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\left(2x^2+10 \right)^{1/3}$$
$$\mathsf{slope} = f'(x) = \frac{1}{3} \left(2x^2 + 10 \right)^{-2/3}(4x)$$

Comment: Slope $=\arctan f'(x)$.

Comment: @Lucian Why $\arctan$?

Answer (score 0):

We have 
\begin{align}
f\left(x\right)=\left(2x^2+10\right)^{1/3},\tag{1}
\end{align}
and the slope at every point in the function's domain (which in this case is all reals, or $x\in\mathbb{R}$) is the derivative with respect to $x$, or
\begin{align}
f'\left(x\right)&=\frac{1}{3}\left(2x^2+10\right)^{-2/3}\left(4x\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{4x}{3\left(2x^2+10\right)^{2/3}}.\tag{3}
\end{align}
Here is a plot of this function and its derivative via Mathematica:

[image]

Note that the blue function is that of $f\left(x\right)$ and the orange is that of $f'\left(x\right)$. Notice that $f'\left(x\right)$ (at least on this restricted interval) 
flip-flops when $f\left(x\right)$ goes from having a negative slope to the left of the origin (and hence the derivative function is negative) while to the right of the origin $f\left(x\right)$ has a positive slope (and hence $f'\left(x\right)$ becomes positive).

I would suggest you go back to the textbook and memorize your rules of differentiation. This is perhaps the easiest topic in Calculus as it's very straight forward and it's possible to find a closed-form solution to (nearly) anything, whereas when you progress you will see there are not closed-form solutions to even "simple" problems.